# Stop running JS when class is added to HTML - Run again when class is removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I have a 'theme toggle' which changes the look/feel of my UI. There is also a custom JS cursor that I don't need on one of the themes. I thought it would be a good idea to kill the script when the relevant class is on `html` as there's a lot of calculation going on with the pointer position. Rather than just use `display: none` and leave the script running.

There are 3 modes/themes:

- Default (always first / onload)
- Dark
- Retro - which is the one where the script should be stopped.

I tried to achieve this using the following method. To test, I add the `.retro` class to `html` so it's the first theme, it does stop the script from running and clicking the toggle turns the script on again. But it only does it once.

Obviously removing the class onload doesn't work either but I just wanted to do the above to see if anything was happening. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong. What's the best approach?

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is: Run this script, unless the class `.retro` is present, if so stop it. If the class `.retro` is removed, run the script again.

```js
/* Toggle */

const html = document.querySelector("html");
const button = document.querySelector(".contrast__link");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (html.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
        html.classList.remove("dark-mode");
        html.classList.add("retro");
        let slideIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
        swiper.destroy(true, true);
        swiper = initSwiper("slide", false, 999999999); // Retro: This should slide, no autoplay or loop
        swiper.slideTo(slideIndex, 0);
    } else if (html.classList.contains("retro")) {
        html.classList.remove("retro");
        let slideIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
        swiper.destroy(true, true);
        swiper = initSwiper("fade", true, 1200); // Default: This should fade, autoplay & loop
        swiper.slideTo(slideIndex, 0);
    } else {
        html.classList.add("dark-mode");
    }
});

/* Cursor */

function createHandler(callback) {
    return function(event) {
        if (!document.documentElement.classList.contains('retro')) {
            callback.call(this, event)
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', createHandler(function() {

    var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
    var cursorTrail = document.querySelector(".cursor-trail");
    var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    var timeout;

    window.addEventListener(
        "mousemove",
        function(e) {
            var x = e.clientX;
            var y = e.clientY;
            cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x - 2}px, ${y - 2}px)`;
            if (!timeout) {
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    timeout = null;
                    cursorTrail.style.transform = `translate(${x - 16}px, ${y - 16}px)`;
                }, 24);
            }
        },
        false
    );

    /**
     * Add/remove classes on click (anywhere).
     */

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
        cursor.classList.add("cursor--click");
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        cursor.classList.remove("cursor--click");
    });
    
    /**
     * Add/remove set classes on hover.
     * 
     * 1. This used to start with `a.forEach((item) => {` but changed to `let` so
     *    that an additional (non-anchor) item could be targeted. `#hello` is for
     *    the image on the 404 page.
     */

    // a.forEach((item) => {
    let links = document.querySelectorAll('a, #hello'); /* [1] */
    links.forEach((item) => { /* [1] */
        item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            cursorTrail.classList.add("cursor-trail--hover");
        });
        item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            cursorTrail.classList.remove("cursor-trail--hover");
        });
    });
    
    /**
     * Add custom classes on hover if the cursor needs to be manipulated in a
     * unique way. If an element has a `data-interaction=""` value set. This will
     * be added as a class to the cursor on hover. For example, this is used to
     * style the prev/next arrows on the carousel.
     *
     * This could be set using a specific class but I've just left it targeting all
     * `a` elements for now. Which will add a class of `undefined` if no dataset is
     * specified.
     */

    a.forEach((item) => {
        const interaction = item.dataset.interaction;

        item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            cursor.classList.add(interaction);
        });
        item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            cursor.classList.remove(interaction);
        });
    });
}))
```

```css
.contrast__link {
  background: white;
}

.cursor {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

.dark-mode {
  background: black;
}

.retro {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="contrast__link">Toggle Classes</a>

<div class="cursor"><span></span></div>
<div class="cursor-trail"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Mykhailo Svyrydovych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13251244/mykhailo-svyrydovych) suggested, to avoid any overhead of the unneeded events call, you would need to have explictly named functions for each event handler, then you could use `removeEventListener` when you're toggling to the retro theme, removing the handler of each `mousemove`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `mouseup` and `mousedown` events that you don't want to run on that theme. Of course, you would need to re-bind all the events again using the proper `addEventListener` calls when toggling to the other two themes.

But I think that, sometimes, the easiest approach is good enough. If you measure the performance and then discover that the events keeping to fire isn't a big concern for your case, go for it. You can easily avoid the unwanted effects of the custom cursor, inside each event handler, just by checking a simple boolean:

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const button = document.querySelector(".contrast__link");
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const cursorTrail = document.querySelector(".cursor-trail");
const a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
let timeout;
let customCursor = true;

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (html.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
    html.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    html.classList.add("retro");
    customCursor = false;
    cursor.style.display = "none";
  } else if (html.classList.contains("retro")) {
    html.classList.remove("retro");
    customCursor = true;
    cursor.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    html.classList.add("dark-mode");
    customCursor = true;
    cursor.style.display = "block";
  }
});

window.addEventListener(
  "mousemove",
  function(e) {
    if (!customCursor) return;
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    cursor.style.display = "block";
    cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x - 2}px, ${y - 2}px)`;
    if (!timeout) {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        cursorTrail.style.transform = `translate(${x - 16}px, ${y - 16}px)`;
      }, 24);
    }
  },
  false
);

document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  if (!customCursor) return;
  cursor.classList.add("cursor--click");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  if (!customCursor) return;
  cursor.classList.remove("cursor--click");
});

let links = document.querySelectorAll('a, #hello');
links.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    if (!customCursor) return;
    cursorTrail.classList.add("cursor-trail--hover");
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    if (!customCursor) return;
    cursorTrail.classList.remove("cursor-trail--hover");
  });
});

a.forEach((item) => {
  const interaction = item.dataset.interaction;
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    if (!customCursor) return;
    cursor.classList.add(interaction);
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    if (!customCursor) return;
    cursor.classList.remove(interaction);
  });
});
```

```css
.contrast__link {
  background: white;
}

.cursor {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.dark-mode {
  background: black;
}

.retro {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="contrast__link">Toggle Classes</a>

<div class="cursor"><span></span></div>
<div class="cursor-trail"></div>
```

*P.S.: I removed the Swiper calls from my code sample because they appeared to be totally unrelated to the question being asked, and were causing console errors.*

Comment: Yeah that's fine (re Swiper), basically a bit like the cursor some of the settings change depending on theme. In theory, I guess these could be used on other blocks pretty easily. For example I have a drag/resize div JS. I could use it the same way like this? https://codepen.io/moy/pen/MWBJMRz

Comment: You can see I've added `resizeElement = false;` to the classes apart from `.retro` (when it should run). Then if you scroll down to the `function initResizeElement()` function you can see I added a `let resizeElement = true;` followed by `if (!resizeElement) return;`?

Comment: Yeah @user1406440, in short, any logic you don't what to run in a specific situation can be dealt by just checking a global boolean variable as I suggested. You just need to think about the default value of the variable, the places where the variable needs to be changed (during theme toggles in your case, as I see), and the places of the code where the variable needs to be checked before running some logic. I'd summarize the thinking talking about side effects: Any place you see a side effect you want to avoid in a specific case, check the variable before that side effect happens in your code.

Comment: Cool! Actually, that last example I just gave doesn't really work. I think it might kill the script but once you resize a div it adds inline CSS. So it's probably that I need to clear as the script stopping doesn't do it along. So that'll be a separate issue ha!

Comment: On something else I have two funtions `function initDragElement() {}` and `function initResizeElement() {}` ...rather than do the above with each of them. Could I rework into something like this `window.onload = function() {
 if (!dragResize) return;
 initDragElement();
 initResizeElement();
};` ...I guess the window.onLoad bit wouldn't work though, I'd need to change that?

Comment: I tried changing the onload to the same as the toggle `button.addEventListener("click", () => {` which stops it running. But once it runs it doesn't disable it again?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to add and **remove** "mousemove" listener inside "click" listener, when you toggling the theme. So if user selects "retro", the event listener should be removed, and when it is another theme, the listener should be added.

Comment: Yeah, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with simple CSS code, it's working

```
 .retro .cursor{
    display:none
}
```

but you want to stop the function also, so tried the following that also worked. When the theme is retro on mouse move the cursor changing function is not calling

```js
/* Toggle */

const html = document.querySelector("html");
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

function addClass() {
  if (html.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
    html.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    html.classList.add("retro");
    cursor.style.display = 'none'

  } else if (html.classList.contains("retro")) {
    html.classList.remove("retro");

  } else {
    html.classList.add("dark-mode");
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (html.classList.contains("retro")) {
    cursor.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    cursor.style.display = 'block'
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x - 2}px, ${y - 2}px)`;
  }
});
```

```css
.cursor {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

.dark-mode {
  background: black;
}

.retro {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
<button onclick='addClass()'>Add Class</button>
```

Comment: I think I need to keep the toggle code the same, as there's some other stuff that's needed for a certain theme. I have another block of code that only needs to run when `.retro` is added (which is probably more important). So was hoping there was maybe an eventListener or something I could wrap the code in. And only run it if the `html` class was equal to `.retro`?

Comment: You can add other stuff in this, I only created a sample code that will solve the issue. You can try this method. If you give any update on this, I can  help you with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use element insertion and `window` properties to load/unload code.
Look at code in snippet, there's simple system for theme changing.
When on retro, mouse clicks will be logged in console.
In my snippet, script will be working only on retro theme, but that doesn't changes concept.

```js
const themeList = {
  'default': {
    enable() {
      app.classList.add('default');
    },
    disable() {
      app.classList.remove('default');
    },
  },
  'dark-mode': {
    enable() {
      app.classList.add('dark-mode');
    },
    disable() {
      app.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    },
  },
  'retro': {
    enable() {
      app.classList.add('retro');
      js = document.createElement("script");
      js.id = 'retroThemeScript';
      js.innerHTML = `
        window.fnToBeRemoved = () => console.log('mouse down');
        app.addEventListener("mousedown", window.fnToBeRemoved);
      ` // you can replace code with next line, so no need to store code in RAM
      //js.src = '/scripts/retroScript.js';
      js.type = 'text/javascript';
      app.appendChild(js);
      this.scriptElement = js;
    },
    disable() {
      app.classList.remove('retro');
      app.removeEventListener('mousedown', window.fnToBeRemoved);
      delete window.fnToBeRemoved;
      app.removeChild(this.scriptElement);
    },
  }
}

const app = document.querySelector('#app');


let currentTheme;

function setTheme(themeName) {
  if (currentTheme)
    themeList[currentTheme].disable();
  themeList[themeName].enable();
  currentTheme = themeName;
}

setTheme('default');
```

```css
#app {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: silver;
}

#app.retro{
  background: magenta;
}

#app.dark-mode { 
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setTheme('default')">Default</button>
<button onclick="setTheme('dark-mode')">Dark</button>
<button onclick="setTheme('retro')">Retro</button>

<div id="app">
  Wanna cake?
</div>
```